# How to make the script work with different files?

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

I have 2 scripts. First, `start.sh` has these lines:

```
echo "-----------RUN copy mta-------------"
bash copy_file.sh mta $today_without_dash
echo "-----------RUN copy rcr-------------"
bash copy_file.sh rcr $today_without_dash
echo "-----------RUN copy sub-------------"
bash copy_file.sh sub $today_without_dash
```

Which starts `copy_file.sh`:

```
echo "remove old files "${1}
hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash /apps/hive/warehouse/database.db/project/file_${1}/*

for i in `hadoop fs -ls /user/files/${2}_C | egrep ${1}.gz | awk -F " " '{print $8}'`
do
    hadoop fs -cp $i /apps/hive/warehouse/database.db/project/file_${1}
    echo "copy file - "${i}
done

for i in `hadoop fs -ls /user/files/${2}_B | egrep ${1}.gz | awk -F " " '{print $8}'`
do
    hadoop fs -cp $i /apps/hive/warehouse/database.db/project/file_${1}
    echo "copy file - "${i}
done
```

The problem is, I have a lot of these `${2}_C` type of folders, that each end with different letter. Like `${2}_P`, `${2}_F`, `${2}_L` and so on. I wondered if there is a way of going through every folder in one loop, instead of writing a loop for every folder. Because the code is getting too bulky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of one loop per `/user/files/${2}_SOMELETTER`,
you could use one loop with all the directories in the parameter list, for example:

```
dirs=(/user/files/${2}_C /user/files/${2}_B)

for i in $(hadoop fs -ls "${dirs[@]}" | egrep ${1}.gz | awk -F " " '{print $8}')
do
    hadoop fs -cp $i /apps/hive/warehouse/database.db/project/file_${1}
    echo "copy file - "${i}
done
```

Note that instead of writing the directory parameters in the `for` statement,
I put them into an array.
This will be more readable if you have many directories.

I also replaced the obsolete `` `...` `` syntax with the modern `$(...)`.